# Sent email from React with body

Tags: reactjs, email

I am using react-share to sent email from react but the body is not getting passed.
Is there any alternative to pass body without using any email services?

```
const handleEmailClick = () => {
const subject = encodeURIComponent('Email Subject');
const body = encodeURIComponent('Email body content.');
window.location.href = `mailto:recipient@example.com? 
subject=${subject}&body=${body}`;};
```

used this code but the body is not showing in the email

Comment: Is the subject working?
Problem may be because of the newline after the recipient.

Comment: yes subject is working